# What's the difference between "recent" and "newest" sort options in my user page?

Tags: support, profile-page, sorting

When I go to my user page to look through all the questions that I have asked, I am always presented with the following choice of sorting options: "recent", "views", "newest", "votes". While I am okay with the second and the forth options, I still don't get the difference between "recent" and "newest". Can anyone here explain it to me, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Recent" sorts by those with the most recent activity of any kind (including replies and edits) first.

"Newest" sorts by the time originally posted, newest first.

Answer (score 2):

The tooltips when you mouse over the sort selection boxes explains:

> [recent] sort by recent activity
>
> [newest] sort by creation date