# Should "RECENT" be replaced with "ACTIVE" in the sort options?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, sorting, recent

At first glance, the difference between RECENT and NEWEST when browsing through a user's questions is unclear. If one scrolls over the label, then it reads

> RECENT: sort by recent activity
>
> NEWEST: sort by creation date

and a simple [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29400/whats-the-difference-between-recent-and-newest-sort-options-in-my-user-page) will also reveal the difference. However, in the Questions tab, these two options are instead labeled

> NEWEST: the most **recently** asked
> questions
>
> ACTIVE: questions that have **recent**
> activity

I think this latter approach is much more clear, since both could be referred to as RECENT. Any chance of changing the profile sort options to match this? Or, any good reason why not to change it?